# Jekyll CSS Loads ONLY for Index.html

Tags: css, github, sass, jekyll

I have been working on a Jekyll website/blog for someone and I am having issues with the css working for anything other than the website's home page.  This makes me think it is an issue with the stylesheet HREF.  I am also getting this error in Chrome dev tool:

`GET https://tanglesandtwists.github.io/macrame/11/17/2018/assets/css/main.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

[Here is the website](https://tanglesandtwists.github.io)
&
[Here is the github project](https://github.com/TanglesAndTwists/tanglesandtwists.github.io)

The website's stylesheets all work fine on my local host when I run `jekyll serve` on the command line.  This is what is confusing me greatly. I understand the font not wanting to load because it is calling HTTP not HTTPS but this is not external and is located in a seperate folder in the directory.

Here is my tree I called that *should* work:

`├───about
├───assets
│   ├───css
│   ├───images
│   │   ├───hero
│   │   ├───posts
│   │   └───thumbnail
│   └───javascripts
│       └───plugins
├───macrame
│   └───11
│       └───17
│           └───2018`

The file in macrame/11/17/18 on line 81 calls:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">`

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.  I have never used Jekyll before, but I found it to be great for making websites for clients that don't know HTML, CSS, JS, JQuery, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
```

Into this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">
```

Your path should be absolute (relative to the root of the site).